# URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly Error

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload a file to dropbox using my flutter mobile app.I get the below error when trying to upload the file to drop box.I'm using the dropbox_client package to access, upload and download a file from dropbox

```
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383): java.lang.IllegalStateException: URI scheme in your 
app's manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a 
com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity with the scheme: db-o9spra3j1p1cwgk
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity.checkAppBeforeAuth(AuthActivity.java:353)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:161)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:147)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:134)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:32)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.dropbox.core.android.Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(Auth.java:24)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.mix1009.dropbox.DropboxPlugin.onMethodCall(DropboxPlugin.java:161)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io- 
flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown 
 Source:12)
 E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):    at 
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#dropbox( 6383):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

E/flutter ( 6383): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
PlatformException(error, URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly. You
should have a com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity with the scheme: db-o9spra3j1p1cwgk,
null, java.lang.IllegalStateException: URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up
correctly. You should have a com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity with the scheme: db-
o9spra3j1p1cwgk
E/flutter ( 6383):   at
com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity.checkAppBeforeAuth(AuthActivity.java:353)

Below is my android manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dropbox_test">
<application
    android:label="dropbox_test"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="db-o9spra3j1p1cwgk" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Comment: look like you didn't add authactivity correctly on manifest file. please add it as new activity as showing their document

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have the necessary URL scheme registered for "com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity" in particular. You can find an example here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/DropboxAndroid/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is here is add an authActivity in that you need to add your dropbox api key in there and this error will be gone..

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
                <data android:scheme="db-yourappkey" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Try to add this code inside manifest , under your mainActivity intent.

you have added it inside intent filter inside your mainActivity intent , remove that and add above mentioned code.

kindly let me know